# Arraylist of classes

Tags: java, arraylist

In my hw assignment my professor says to create a data field of type ArrayList. He wants them to be instances of a class. 
I'm not exactly sure what that means, but my guess is

```
    ArrayList<CLassName> list = ArrayList<ClassName>();
```

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: I doubt that anyone beside your professor could confirm it, but your guess seems very probable. Anyway you can also improve you code by using `List` interface as reference to `ArrayList`.

Comment: You should confirm this with your professor, because only he/she knows what he/she really means and expects.

Comment: @Pshemo `List<CLassName> list = ArrayList<ClassName>();`? What would the difference be between the two?

Comment: Who is toggling their downvote? Why?

Comment: @tbodt It was me, was testing vote animations :)

Comment: @Pshemo april fools? or what?

Comment: @Pshemo can you stop please?

Comment: @ChrisVachon "What would the difference be between the two" [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) should answer your question.

Comment: I guess I should have specified a little better. I know what the professor wants, is that the correct syntax? It's seems you are in agreement of that.

Comment: @Cupcake Just did. There are not so many animations to test. Sorry if that bothered you.

Comment: @Pshemo That is way too much for me to read right now, so I will trust you on changing to "List" instead of "ArrayList" and read that sometime tomorrow when I'm not in a hurry. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Since Java SE 1.7, it can a little simpler:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

NOTE: The rest is background knowledge about ArrayLists.

Let's say you want an ArrayList of Strings. Keep in mind Strings are Objects.

```
// Creates ArrayList
ArrayList<String> list = ArrayList<String>();

// Adds elements to ArrayList
list.add("Hello");
list.add("world!");

// Iterate through ArrayList
for (String str : list) {
    // Print the String in the list.
    System.out.print(str + " ");
}
// Print newline character.
System.out.print("\n");
```

The `for (String str : list)` is a *for each loop* which allows you to iterate through each element in the list.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Now it does, but it has a lot of redundant content.

Comment: @tbodt I need to get into the habit of reading the questions before answering, but what about now.

Comment: I think that the OP is learning about how to use `ArrayList`s in his class.

Comment: Well that's why I includede the information, but yeah I could have answered the question the first time around...

Comment: "Let's say you want an ArrayList of Strings. Keep in mind Strings are Objects." That is literally all I needed to see to confirm what I was looking for. I always forget that Strings are objects because my first programming class they taught us that they were primitives. And that was my belief for about a year, so somtimes it just slips my mind.

Comment: @ChrisVachon in some languages they are primatives, and they are declared literally and automatically translated to a String object so they can be misleading. In addition, the java compiler accepts adding for concatanation, which can be misleading. Glad I could help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. I do, however, recommend this instead:

```
List<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
```

That way you can change the type of list in just one place instead of two.